# Style ASP.net DropDownList Not Select Element DropDown List

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, dropdown

I want to style my asp dropdownlist but all solutions I found online are all related to dropdownlist with select element. Now I am currently using bootstrap to try to get the output shown below, but I could use other methods like css and jquery too as long as I could achieve the output shown below.

This is the output I have currently:

[image]
This is the output I want to achieve:
[image]
This is my code:

```
    //aspx file
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".form-control").form - control();

    });

</script>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" Width="136px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="form-control">
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: From your example it looks like thats a bootstrap drop down button, not a drop down

Comment: hi @code, i created with asp dropdown list, but now using bootstrap to style my dropdown. I can use css or jquery to style my dropdown too as long as I could achieve the output as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

As I said earlier thats a button drop down you are trying to achieve you have to add the bootstrap class **btn btn-default** to your dropdown as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" Width="136px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="btn btn-default form-control">
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="btn btn-default">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I have created a pen for you to test [Test it here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbxqdw)

Comment: hi @code, thanks for your reply, but I don't think I can use bootstrap to style my dropdown anymore because bootstrap css will damage my whole website design. Do you have any other workarounds for this? It is especially hard to change the asp.net dropdown arrow..

Comment: @Felicia Soh Why will bootstrap throw off your css? you should have your css file listed after the bootstrap css so it doesnt throw off your own settings